# List files and timestamp of creation on AIX system (Perl)

Tags: perl, timestamp, aix

I want to perform a command like `ls -l --time-style="+%s"` on an AIX system.
I only need the timestamp of the file and the filename.

With [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137224), I made:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -le 'print((stat shift)[9])' {} \;
```

But I can't find a way to print the filename with Perl (I don't know the language and have troubles with the one-liner syntax).
I'm experimenting with something like this:

```
perl -le 'print((stat shift)[9] . " ???")' foo.txt
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You don't need Perl for this: `find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n'`. If you do use Perl, it would be more efficient to pipe the output from `find` directly to `perl` so you don't invoke the interpreter separately for each file: `find . -type f -print0 | perl -0E 'say((stat)[9] . " $_") while <>'` (I think `-print0` is a GNU extension so your version of `find` may not have it.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot On my AIX 7.1 system, there isn't `-printf` or `-print0` on the find command. I don't know if an improvement is still possible...

Comment: So I guess you do need Perl. `-print0` allows you to process filenames containing newlines safely; if you're sure none of your filenames contain newlines, you could modify the second command I gave to `find . -type f | perl -nlE 'say((stat)[9] . " $_")'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `@ARGV` array, which you can use to loop over, and check `$_` for current file name,

```
perl -le 'print((stat $_)[9] . " $_") for @ARGV' foo.txt
```

Comment: `$_` is default argument for `stat()` so it can be omitted.

Comment: I will never understand the Perl syntax. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @pihug12 ok, this is equivalent which you're more familiar with, `perl -le 'for my $f (@ARGV) { print((stat $f)[9] . " $f"); }'`